# First and second moments of two correlated functions

Tags: probability, correlation, covariance, moment-generating-functions

I am trying to find the first and second moments of the following:

$k=mk^{-b}$

where $m \sim U[a,b]$ (discrete) and $k^{-b}$ is a power law distribution

I know how to find the first and second moments of both independently, just not the product. And also, how will it change if they are not correlated? just remove the Cov portion? thank you